# Drupal: edit content pages... why do my Save button is there?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

how is possible that the Save button is positioned here ?!!

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/SaveButton.png

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One module does something funny with the weight values of the form elements.

Comment: how can I assign different weight to save button ? Should be very high ?

Comment: This is done one of the modules what you have enabled. The submit button should have the greates weight in the form, but this can be easily overwritten.

Comment: how can I re-assign high weight to Save Button ?

Comment: Try to find out which module does it, or if not, create a small module, which hook_form_alter, and give a big value to the submit button's #weight property.

Comment: I've tried to add to template.php file in my theme folder:   *$form['submit']['#weight']  = 100;* but it doesn't work.   *$form['author']['#weight']  = 100;* works, and   *$form['submit']['#value']  = "Hello";* also works! (even if the label is not replaced... the text is just added before the button

Comment: I've solved adding ['buttons']['#weight'] = 100 in template.php